# list files names in a ftp server's file

Tags: java, eclipse, file, ftp

I want to list the files in a directory located in a ftp server but I have some errors like:

```
drwxrwxrwx    3 1004     1004         4096 Jan 17  2017 ftp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My code:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://username:pass@hostname:port");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}

File cur = new File("/ftp/files/assignment/");
getAllFiles(cur);}}
}

public static void getAllFiles(File curDir){
    long len = 0;
    long time = curDir.lastModified();
    File[] filesList = curDir.listFiles();
    for(File f : filesList){
        len += f.length();
        if(f.isDirectory())
        {
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " " + len + " " + time);
        }
        if(f.isFile()){
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " " + len + " " + time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a stacktrace

Comment: what is stacktrace

Comment: A listing normally produced when the program runs and encountes an exception.

Comment: It has linenumbers telling where the exception occurs.

Comment: It is normally printed to the console. If you run the program from a IDE it should be visible there - unless you have redirected standard out and err.

Comment: oh, getAllFiles(cur);}} line is throwing an exception. But when I used this method with my root directory, the code works. However, I think I couldn't get the files from the server.

Comment: Why don't you use a library for FTP instead?

Comment: I used apache common io for the rest of the methods. but firstly I couldn't manage the ftp's file. I wasn't aware of the library at the beginning, so I implemented the rest with apache.

Answer (score 0):

`File` only works with *local* files, not files on a remote FTP-server, and `/ftp/files/assignment/` does not exist on your local machine (so `listFiles()` return null causing your for-loop to crash).

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles() - "*Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.*"